# What is the VB.Net/C# equivalent of ADSYSTEMINFO, and is it needed to interact with AD in this example?

Tags: c#, vb.net, asp-classic, directoryservices

I'm looking at some old ASP code that contains the following:

```
Set objDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("adsysteminfo") 
Set objUser= Getobject("LDAP://" & Replace(objSysInfo.UserName,"/","\/"))
dtmValue = objUser.PasswordLastChanged

objMaxPwdAge = GetObject("LDAP://" & objDSE.get("DefaultNamingContext")).maxPwdAge

dblMaxPwdDays = Abs(objMaxPwdAge.HighPart * 2^32 + objMaxPwdAge.LowPart) _
                * ONE_HUNDRED_NANOSECOND / SECONDS_IN_DAY

pwdExpDate = dtmValue + dblMaxPwdDays
```

This is for an intranet app that uses integrated authentication.

Is there a replacement for the ASP adsysteinfo object?  I can probably port most of the LDAP calls using `System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry`, but is there a better/easier way to do this in ASP.NET (VB.Net or C#)?

Is there any documentation for how to convert the ASP object properties to DirectoryEntry properies?

Comment: Are you working in classic ASP or ASP.net ?

Comment: Current code is classic asp, and I need to duplicate the functionality in asp.net.

Answer (score 1):

In your example code, adsysteminfo is just use to retrieve the current user name. In an ASP.Net application, you can get this one of two ways, depending on your configuration:

1) If you are impersonating each user, then you should be able to use:

```
Return System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
```

2) If you are not impersonating the user, but you do have integrated authentication as the only security mechanism for the web site, then you can get the user's domain name as follows:

```
Return Request.ServerVariables("logon_user")
```

As for the other LDAP call, System.DirectoryServices is definitely what you want to use. Here is a sample of how we get hooked into AD to start searching for users:

```
Private m_Searcher As DirectorySearcher
Private m_sNamingContext As String

    Dim theRootEntry As DirectoryEntry
    Dim theEntry As DirectoryEntry
    Dim theNamingContext As Object

    ' First, fetch any information that we need from the database
    If Not GetConfigurationInfoFromDB() Then
        Return False
    End If

    ' Obtain the domain root entry
    theRootEntry = New DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://RootDSE")
    ' Verify that we retrieved it correctly and raise an error if we did not
    If theRootEntry Is Nothing Then
        Throw New Exception("A directory services entry for the LDAP RootDSE could not be created.")
    End If

    ' Get the root naming context
    theNamingContext = theRootEntry.Properties("rootDomainNamingContext").Value
    ' Verify that we retrieved it correctly and raise an error if we did not
    If (theNamingContext Is Nothing) OrElse (theNamingContext.ToString().Length = 0) Then
        Throw New Exception("The root domain naming context property could not be retrieved from the LDAP directory services")
    Else
        m_sNamingContext = theNamingContext.ToString()
    End If

    ' And create a new directory entry for the root naming context
    theEntry = New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" & m_sNamingContext)
    ' Verify that we retrieved it correctly and raise an error if we did not
    If theEntry Is Nothing Then
        Throw New Exception("A directory entry object could not be created for LDAP://" & m_sNamingContext)
    End If

    ' Now we configure what we are looking for from Active Directory

    ' Start with a new searcher for the root domain
    m_Searcher = New DirectorySearcher(theEntry)
```

Then we can use m_Searcher to start extracting what we need from AD (this is just one example for using directory services).

Comment: So how do I search for the maxPwdAge using m_Searcher?